# UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary memory warning and crash, but .SavedPhotosAlbum is very ok

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

select picture from album with `UIImagePickerController`. when set sourceType to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary`, one of my test device crash everytime(iphone 6,64g.  only this device, other devices are ok) ,but set the sourceType to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum` is ok,no memory warning,no crash. why? somebody else met this problem?

Comment: can you show the crash log? log is helpfull for others to find out the reason

Comment: can comment your code what you tried  and show crash log . it may helpful to find the issue.

Comment: it is weird....there is not crash log in this device logs about this app.....only some tip in the console of xcode: "2016-04-15 18:17:23.046 FlashCute[2505:865699] Received memory warning.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" .    sorry , I do not know how to format the code in the  comment area.